# Data insert into SQL Server from C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm attempting to insert some data into Microsoft SQL Server, all the data inserted until it gets to the final table `scmd3`. Any ideas as to why its not inserting into that table?

Here is my code I have so far... I've tried everything I can think of any help would be appreciated... thanks in advance guys.

Comment: You get any exception or error message?

Comment: No, nothing... I just doesn't insert the proper data into the final table unless it is explicitly defined. it contains 0 where other assigned integers should be.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table that's stopping the insert from happening?

Comment: what do you mean "explicitly defined"? If you put in hard coded values it works?

Comment: Is your function being called?

Comment: paqogomez yes... and N West no there isn't... I'm completely lost

Comment: Put a breakpoint and see what happens.

Comment: I suspect that there is a problem with the parameter values - perhaps a string too long or a conversion error. Is there a try-catch around this code? If you place a fourth insert below the last one in the code, does it execute?

Comment: Breakpoint placed... its still places 0 in the userInfo.Sleep and userInfo.Repeat... I can see that the converted textbox contains the proper integer but it doesnt reflect on the SQL table...

Comment: @KeithPayne you should say that... tried that also... did not execute

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string** please?

Comment: If one of the variables you're using as values in `.AddWithValue` is `null` then it will not be able to determine what type to send to the database. That could make it go wrong.

Comment: If you solved your own problem either post your own answer and accept it or delete your question, do not leave the question unanswered or answered with no accepted answer or it will keep getting auto populated to the front page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: The error wasn't within the insert service code it was in the I service... Just simply adding a question mark solved all my problems. Added the question mark after int, also added the if statement and now everything works beautifully!!!! Posting the answer because if somenoe had posted anything remotely close it would have saved me a days worth of work looking for a single solution... THANKS for all of you that helped.

```
[DataMember]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int? InitialSleep { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int? RepeatPeriod { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int? RepeatTimes { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public DateTime? LastSent { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public int TimeSent { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
```

if statement:

```
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
        userInfo.InitialSleep = null;
    else
        userInfo.InitialSleep = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```